How can I limit selection of checkboxes upto a certain number among all checkboxes ?? React
trying to implement a feature that limits the number of addons a user can select based on the max_select          property of each group. If a user tries to select more addons than the specified maximum, an error message should be displayed. Also if user has selected maxSelect number of addons then rest of unselected one gets disbaled. Means in a group used would be able to select any max_select number of addons only.
Code: https://codeshare.io/LjWoVV
or here: https://shorturl.at/glyD4
*>! in file line number 592*

const [flagArr, setFlagArr] = useState([]);

const handlePlusClick = (arr) => {
if (!arr || !arr.groups || !arr.groups.length || !arr.groups[0].addon) {
    return;
}

let addonGroupType = arr.groups[0].addon_group_type;
let newFlagArr = [];

if (addonGroupType === 1) {
    for (let item of arr.groups[0].addon) {
        if (item?.addon_id.active === true) {
            newFlagArr.push(false);
        }
    }
}

setFlagArr(newFlagArr);
    // console.log(newFlagArr, "flag array on clicking plusOutlined");
};`

`const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(() => new Array(flagArr.length).fill(false));

const selectedCount = checkedState.reduce((sum, currentState) => {
    return currentState ? sum + 1 : sum;
}, 0);`

*// Render - in file line number 867*

`<input
    type="checkbox"
    className="check2 checkbox1"
    value={val}
    onChange={(e) => {
        // handleOnChange(idx, e)
        handleSelectAddon(
            e.target.checked,
            item?.addon_id,
            idx,
            addons?.groups,
            val?.id,
            val?.addon_group_type,
            val?.max_select
        );
        const updatedCheckedState = [...checkedState];
        updatedCheckedState[idx] = e.target.checked;
        setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);
    }}
    checked={checkedState[idx]}
    disabled={!checkedState[idx] && selectedCount >= 1}
/>`


State what your problem is. What is not happening that you expect to happen? What is happening instead? What are the circumstances where this occurs? What do you need help with? Stating the technology stack explicitly also wouldn't go amiss.

Problem: There are items/addons and their checkboxes to select them among a group of items. There is this max_select field which basically states number of checkboxes that can be selected (meaning number of items that can be selected).
I was implementing the function where when ‘max_select’ number of addons are selected then rest of checkboxes gets disabled. So, user can’t click on them to select. For e.g. if there are 4 items/addons and max_select == 2 then I can select any two only.

I made a flagArray which tracks the state unchecked or checked based on that If checked ones are greater than max_select all the false ones gets disabled.
This is the checkbox code with JSON that is getting mapped:  https://codeshare.io/g8edOw

and basically i'm not able to implement it. Project is using NEXT.js (JS)
